# Get browser response headers on API call (I'm using Meteor but vanilla would be helpful too)

Tags: javascript, http, meteor, http-headers, response

I'm making an API call (specifically to stubhub) and I want to get the response headers found in the browser network tab:

[image: Snapshot of browser network tab]

Here's my API call (using Meteor HTTP)

```
HTTP.post('https://api.stubhub.com/login', {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64
  },
  params: {
    'grant_type' : 'password',
    'username' : username,
    'password' : password,
    'scope' : 'PRODUCTION'
  }
}, function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log(res);
  }

})
```

I console.log 'res' to see everything, and I saw a few objects but main ones are header and data. Data is the content object which is usable in other ways, but header just returns this:

[image: Console.log of res]

How do I get the Response Headers?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was making this call client-side (obviously not secure, just to get my app up and running/testing). If you make the call server-side, say via a Meteor method, the full header field will be available in the response.